# Unable to run Android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

I was trying to run this application, source code for the complete application is here: http://microblogging.wingnity.com/downloads/MicroBlog.zip

When I try to import the project, it imports and gives an error at running "No Module named MicroBlog". I guess there is some problem with the project.

It's a blog application where multiple people can comment and see them at: http://microblogging.wingnity.com/

Can anyone please try and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, rename project from your project Explorer

and try to import project by this

first extract .zip

then import project by

file > import > existing android code into workspace > rename project name

and finish

Comment: Are you able to run it.

Comment: Can you post a comment? because i can't see it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/19lcd7nmgu33wmv/Screenshot_2014-02-09-13-28-13.png

Comment: You can see login page of that project which i have imported from that zip file into my eclipse

Comment: Yes, I can see it. Great. Can you post a comment? how to rename the project? I can't do it. Should i delete and copy it again?

Comment: first rename project in eclipse if already exists, by selecting project name and just right click on that project and then import this newly project, because you can not import same name project into eclipse. and after that if you face any problem please elaborate problem. so i can understand it very well

Comment: Thanks nil, I deleted the project and copied it again in the "workspace" folder and I am able to import it and also i am able to post the comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, I did it. Sorry new to Stackoverflow.